# how can I read table hive in a .orc file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I have a .orc file, is there a way to convert it to a .csv file? or is there another way to read the tables within this file?

Comment: What you means by read tables ? `select * from table ` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hive has native `ORC` support, so you can read it directly via Hive.

**Illustration:**

(Say, the file is named `myfile.orc`)

**Upload file to HDFS**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs:///my_table_orc_file
hadoop fs -put myfile.orc hdfs:///my_table_orc_file
```

**Create a Hive table on it**

(Update column definitions to match the data)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table_orc`(
  `col1` string,
  `col2` string)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION
  'hdfs:///my_table_orc_file';
```

**Query it**

```
select * from my_table_orc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read content of ORC file using following command

```
hive --orcfiledump -d <path_of_orc_file_in_hdfs>
```

It will return the content as json.